# how to find name john and replace with smith in Laravel from name column of a table

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

My String from name Column

**john_items.3**

I want to fetch all these names that start with the john and replace all of them with smith and update columns like

```
**john_items.3**
```

will become

```
**smith_items.3**
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$replacedItems = \App\Models\ModelName::where('name', 'LIKE','john'.'%' )
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($item) {
        $item->name = str_replace('john', 'smith', $item->name);
        $item->save();

        return $item;
    });

// Print all
dd($replacedItems->toArray());
```

Comment: This error is showing Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::save()

Comment: Did you add the proper model name?